# How can I remove this aerator?

Tags: plumbing

I tried multiple aerator keys and they aren't working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears to have 8 holes around the edge. A pin-spanner or suitable approximation* could be stuck in two of them and turned.

*Tips of needle-nosed pliers (but probably not your nice ones, since it's not what they are designed for), suitable sized nails in properly spaced holes drilled in a hunk of wood, snap ring pliers (but probably not your nice ones, since it's not what they are designed for,) projections of appropriate size and spacing you don't grind or file  away from a bit of scrap metal you can get a wrench or locking pliers on to apply force.

Comment: I agree, but I don't understand your caveats. What could that plastic possibly do to "your nice ones"?

Comment: It's torquing the joint in the wrong direction. Best reserved for the pliers you also use as a hammer and for prying paint cans open, not the good ones.

Comment: I guess I just don't have any pliers that are "good enough" to worry about. Maybe if I had a $150 pair from Snap-On or Matco?

Comment: That makes sense. I've seen some get loose that way.

Answer (score 0):

Cut a slot in the plastic with a dremel tool and then stick a quarter in the slot and turn it out.

Comment: That's just unnecessary with all those existing slots.